How to set header in Jboss 6.1
I am using Jboss 6.1 to run the application, if anyone know that how to set the header in jboss 6.1, in which files we need to make the changes to set header in jboss 6.1
I added the filter in server.xml which is present in 'default\deploy\jbossweb.sar' location but it didn't work. I added filter also in web.xml file which is present 'default\deploy\http-invoker.sar\invoker.war\WEB-INF' location but same it didn't work for me.

Does this answer your question? Set Http header using Jboss6.1

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
